# OpenGL Vertex Value Range (GLFloat)

Tags: opengl, graph, coordinates, coordinate-systems, vertex

I'm learning OpenGL and having a hard time finding a clear definition of the coordinate system.

How can you tell what numeric range of values will show up in the viewport?

Comment: Alas, I'm using Gl 3.0, so some of the matrix stuff wont help until I go set it up myself :) from what I understand anyway. Thanks for the quick answers.

Comment: Then the range I gave you (-1 to +1) applies to the output of your vertex shader (i.e. the `gl_Vertex` variable it assigns).

Comment: @Ben: ah thanks, suddenly the answer seems obvious because of shader output lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-1.0 to +1.0 (after all transformations are applied).

This information is buried in the [`glViewport` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374202.aspx) in a somewhat roundabout way.  I'm choosing the MSDN version of the documentation because more other online sources mangle the formula during conversion to HTML (it's the correct formulat, but not recognizable).

You can get any pre-transformation coordinate system you want by applying appropriate scaling and translation factors.  `glOrtho` makes this easy in GL 1.x - 2.x.  In OpenGL 3.x, you use a vertex shader to do transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Range of vertex values visible are governed by two transformation matrices, **ModelView** and **Projection**. **ModelView** matrix is constructed with `glRotate`, `glTranslate` type of operations and **Projection** matrix is created with `glOrtho`, `glPerspective` or `gluLookAt`.

A vertex V is transformed into viewport coordinates with the below transformation and non-visible portions are culled in the target space ([-1,1] for all axes).

```
V'' = Projection * ModelView * V
```

However `glOrtho` an `glPerspective` gets visibility ranges as input given in modelview space. These ranges are comparable with the transformed vertex:

```
V' = ModelView * V
```

If you are using an identity matrix as `ModelView`, you can compare your vertex values with those given to `glOrtho` or `glPerspective`.